# Does kubernetes run new virtual machines on new machines when autoscale pods?

Tags: kubernetes, openstack, kubernetes-pod

i'm reading about kubernetes but i don't have understand if kubernetes has the ability to run new virtual machines on new machines and then start the pods on them or if the set of machines in which operate are fixed and must be always running. I'll use kubernetes on top of openstack. Thanks

Comment: What tools do you using to build a Kubernetes cluster?
(e.g. kubeadm, rancher, and kops)
The answer to your question is dependent above tools.

Comment: am I correct you are asking about node autoscaler?

Answer (score 0):

Providing answer blindly as have no comments from author.
First of all I would like recommend you read [Theory of Auto-Scaling](https://docs.openstack.org/auto-scaling-sig/latest/theory-of-auto-scaling.html) article, as you mentioned you will use k8s on top of openstack.

In openstack conceptual diagram looks like this
[image]

And below are the components that can be controlled with Auto-Scaling.

- Compute Host
- VM running on a Compute Host
- Container running on a Compute Host
- Network Attached Storage
- Virtual Network Functions

So answer your question - yes
What I would also like to show - read about [Heat](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Heat) component and [Autoscaling with heat](https://docs.openstack.org/senlin/latest/scenarios/autoscaling_heat.html)